# Voltage notch behavior

Tags: rectifier, three-phase

I am using software to simulate and learn more about 3-phase semi-conductor rectifiers (using SCR.) I also learn about the voltage notches due to the possible overlap between the SCR commutation. If I am correct the voltage notches appear on the input voltage.

So my problem is, no matter what angles I used on the SCR or experiments I make, I can't see any voltage notches happening on the input voltage.

Can someone help me and tell me how I can "force" or proper simulate the circuit in order to see the voltage notches happening?

Comment: You said it yourself: you need to *overlap* the command triggers. That is, ensure that any two adjacent pulses are on at the same time. You'll also need to make sure the source is not an ideal voltage source, it needs to have a finite resitance (impedance) so that there is a voltage drop when cross-conducting occurs.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen thank you for the tips. But what you mean with two adjacent pulseS? Can you give a example of the pulse on each SCR in degress? For example if SCR - pulse at 30º , should I put SCR3 - pulse at 30º also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjacent means two pulses that occur, temporal-wise, next to each other. Here is an example of cross-conducting for a half-bridge, a simple case for the sake of exemplification:

[image: test]

`V1` and `V2` should be complementary and for that `V2` needs to be delayed by half the period (`500 ms`) compared to `V1`. The values within the small rectangles show the delay of each source, and for `V2` you can see that the delay is `550 ms`, thus `50 ms` more than needed. In rest, the pulse width and rising/falling times are the same, which means that the pulses will look temporally aligned as seen in the upper plot (`V(a)` and `V(b)`) -- they overlap.

During that portion, both switches will conduct, resulting in a shorting of the power supply (here simplistically modeled with two capacitors). As a result, the waveform across the load will look as if would have a dead-time (lowerplot, `V(x)`), but the current through the switches will show the atrocities (lower plot, `I(S1)`): that big spike on top of the normal load.

For your case, the 3-phase voltage source should have at the very least some series resistance, such that when the cross-conducting current spike occurs, the increased voltage drop would be reflected back to the source, resulting in those "notches" you mentioned. What values you need, that's up to you to think for whatever case you have.

Note that the values I used are quite mild, `100 Ohms` for the ON-resistance compared to `1 kOhm` for load, and there's no dead-time, so that you can see the effect of cross-conducting while being able to compare it to the normal load, but in reality this error can result in indian circuits (something to do with the smoke).

Comment: thank you for your time and explanations. I think I am understanding the theory behind this but I still not getting able to see the voltage notches in simulation and I am getting crazy because I think I should see them, because other people used the same circuit and software (PSIM) to show this. Can you see on my original post (edited) if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: @Dimitri9494  If you'd stop a bit to think about it, you'd know. I said you need some resistance inseries with the 3-phase source such that when a current spike occurs, it causes a voltage drop *across the resistor*. You've added the resistors, but where do you think is the best place to measure that voltage drop: before, or after it occurs? Hint: it's not where you are measuring. :-)

Comment: Think of it this way: that resistance is supposed to be built in the wall plug, you can't take it out. So when you measure, you automatically include that, it's impossible to do it otherwise.

Comment: Buddy you are 100% right! I feel "stupid" mas I guess this is the learning process. Thank you for you patience and you last tip. It makes completely sense. I done the measure on the proper place and now I can see what I want to see.

Comment: Glad I could help. And you should be glad for being able to "feel stupid" -- it's the best way to improve youself (though being too harsh can be adverse).